# CreateConnection method doesn't exits in DefaultSolrStartUp - Sitecore 9.3

Tags: solr, content-search

I am in process of upgrading content serach Solr provider from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.3.
I am facing some code issue after upgraded the dll(Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider, Version=6.0.0.0)

facing issue in creationconnection which is override from Defaultsolr setup

In the upgraded DLL Creationconnection override method does not exits.

```
public class DefaultSolrStartUp
{
    public DefaultSolrStartUp();
    [Obsolete("Please use the default constructor.")]
    public DefaultSolrStartUp(IHttpWebRequestFactory requestFactory, BaseSolrSpecificSettings solrSettings);

    protected IEnumerable<ISearchIndex> Indexes { get; }
    [Obsolete("The property is not used and will be removed in the future.")]
    protected virtual BaseSolrSpecificSettings SolrSettings { get; }
    [Obsolete("The property is not used and will be removed in the future.")]
    protected virtual IHttpWebRequestFactory RequestFactory { get; }
    protected internal virtual DefaultSolrLocator<Dictionary<string, object>> Operations { get; internal set; }
    [Obsolete("The property is not used and will be removed in the future.")]
    protected internal ISolrConnector SolrConnector { get; set; }

    public virtual void Initialize();
}
```

Code implementation

```
public class SolrPostStartUp : DefaultSolrStartUp
{
    protected override ISolrConnection CreateConnection(string serverUrl)
    {
        SolrConnection basecon = new SolrConnection(serverUrl) { Timeout = SolrContentSearchManager.ConnectionTimeout };


        FieldInfo field = typeof(DefaultSolrStartUp).GetField("solrCache", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var basecache = field.GetValue(this);
        if (basecache != null)
        {
            basecon.Cache = (ISolrCache)basecache;
        }
        PostSolrConnection solrConnection = new PostSolrConnection(basecon, serverUrl);
        return solrConnection;
    }
}
```

Could someone please suggest the approach for the issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Let's firstly define, why do you need it?

It looks like your code forces Solr to use `POST` requests instead of `GET` requests.
It is usually done to prevent error `The remote server returned an error: (414) Request-URI Too Long`. This error can appear if you use `GET` request and have quite a long search query.

If my assumption about the purpose of your code is right then here is the solution.
Sitecore 9.3 has ability to turn usage of `POST` requests on/off from the config file.

1. Open `App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`
2. Find `ContentSearch.Solr.SendPostRequests` setting
3. Set value to be `true`

And now, you don't need to override any methods in default `DefaultSolrStartUp`.

P.S. It is better [to patch config](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/configuration-patch-file-examples.html) rather than change it directly.